# What is meant by "$n$ times differentiable function"?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I understand that a polynomial function will be differentiable till we get a constant. But what about other functions? For example $y=\sin x$?

If a question says that a function is (suppose) twice differentiable, should we assume that it is a polynomial function?

Comment: To improve your question, do you mind indicating the motivation (the reason) for asking your question?

Comment: @TobyMak In a lot of questions I saw the phrase 'If f(x) is twice differentiable....' and i didn't know what to make of that. In the solution to one of such problems, f(x) turned out to be sin x and I was confused because I thought that sin x was infinitely differentiable

Comment: It means you can differentiate it _at least_ $n$ times.

Comment: So can a linear function be  twice differentiable?

Comment: *"I understand that a polynomial function will be differentiable till we get a constant."* ... A constant function is still differentiable, so a polynomial is another example of an infinitely-differentiable function.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special for a function to be twice-differentiable. As you may not have known, the trigonometric functions ($\sin x, \cos x, \tan x$ and their inverse functions), exponential functions, and in general most continuous functions (that you will see in a problem) are twice-differentiable. This can be proved by finding $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ and repeating this process again.

What this means is that you can take the derivative of a function twice without worrying if $f'(x)$ or $f''(x)$ are properly defined. This also means that you do not need to calculate the third derivative or any further derivatives.  This comes in useful in problems involving integration by parts, where you need to differentiate once every time you apply integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is differentiable if the ratio $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ has a limit as $h\to 0$ for any value of $x$. In this case, call this ratio $f'(x)$.

The key observation is that $f'$ *is again a function*, so you can iterate : $f$ is twice differentiable if $f'$ is differentiable, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Example of a non-polynomial function which is two times differentiable:

$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{x^2}{2} &,x\geq 0\\ \\ \frac{-x^2}{2} &,x<0\end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial is infinitely differentiable: a constant's derivative is $0$, and $0$ is a constant, so has $(x \rightarrow 0)$ (itself) as a derivative.

sin(x) is also infinitely differentiable, in a cycle that goes sin(x) -> cos(x) -> -sin(x) -> -cos(x) -> sin(x).

An example of a function (over $\mathbb{R}$) which is only once differentiable is $(x \rightarrow x |x|)$. Its derivative is $(x \rightarrow |x|)$, but it has no second derivative, as the absolute value has no derivative at $0$ (the curve makes an angle there, so the left and right derivatives at $x = 0$ don't match).

Answer (score 0):

A constant function, of which the zero function is an example, is also infinitely differentiable:  $$\frac{d}{dx}[0] = 0.$$

In my experience, when an author states that a function is $n$ times differentiable, this is intended to mean that derivatives up to and including order $n$ exist; it does not impose any restrictions on the existence of higher order derivatives.  For instance, $\sin x$ is $n$ times differentiable for any positive integer $n$.

Functions that are *exactly* $n$ times differentiable might be better characterized by stating that derivatives of higher order do not exist.  Such an example is $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{n+1}, & x > 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ -x^{n+1} & x < 0. \end{cases}$$  Then derivatives up to and including order $n$ exist at $x = 0$, but not any higher.